# Applying variable transparency to an image in java

Tags: java, python, image, transparency, gradient

I'm wondering how to apply a variable mask to an image's transparency in Java (presumably using buffered image). So, for instance, I want to apply a mask such as the following:

[image: Mask]

To the an image such as the following:

[image: Cute Cat]

In order to get:

[image]

It's important that the transparency is changed by the gradient, not just the color, because I want to be able to to this kind of thing:

[image]

I've found an incredibly slow way of achieving this by going through and setting the transparency value of every single pixel manually, but as I said, it's super slow. What should I be looking at to try to accomplish this? Or should I even be doing it in Java? I've been getting to know python recently, so if anyone thinks it's better to try this sort of thing with a particular python module, that would be useful information as well.

Thank in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to get a transparent mask.

GradientMask.java:

```
import Utilities.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.imageio.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.io.*;
public class GradientMask {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        JFrame Main = new JFrame("Gradient Mask");
        JLabel imageLayer = new JLabel();
        JLabel maskLayer = new JLabel();
        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File("C:\\Users\\"+System.getenv("username")+"\\Desktop\\Cat Image.jpg"));
        BufferedImage gradientMask = new GradientImage(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), new Color[]{new Color(255, 255, 255, 125), Color.BLACK}, GradientImage.RADIAL_FROM_CENTER).getImage();
        Main.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Main.setBounds(100, 50, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());
        imageLayer.setBounds(0, 0, Main.getWidth(), Main.getHeight());
        maskLayer.setBounds(0, 0, Main.getWidth(), Main.getHeight());
        imageLayer.setIcon(new ImageIcon((Image) image));
        maskLayer.setIcon(new ImageIcon((Image) gradientMask));
        Main.getContentPane().add(imageLayer);
        imageLayer.add(maskLayer);
        Main.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

GradientImage.java:

```
package Utilities;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
public class GradientImage {
    public final static int LINEAR_LEFT_TO_RIGHT = 1;
    public final static int LINEAR_RIGHT_TO_LEFT = 2;
    public final static int LINEAR_TOP_TO_BOTTOM = 3;
    public final static int LINEAR_BOTTOM_TO_TOP = 4;
    public final static int LINEAR_DIAGONAL_UP = 5;
    public final static int LINEAR_DIAGONAL_DOWN = 6;
    public final static int RADIAL_FROM_TOP_LEFT_CORNER = 7;
    public final static int RADIAL_FROM_BOTTOM_LEFT_CORNER = 8;
    public final static int RADIAL_FROM_TOP_RIGHT_CORNER = 9;
    public final static int RADIAL_FROM_BOTTOM_RIGHT_CORNER = 10;
    public final static int RADIAL_FROM_CENTER = 11;
    public final static int RADIAL_FROM_CORNERS = 12;
    public final static int PATH_FROM_CENTER = 13;
    public final static int PATH_FROM_TOP_LEFT_CORNER = 14;
    public final static int PATH_FROM_TOP_RIGHT_CORNER = 15;
    public final static int PATH_FROM_BOTTOM_LEFT_CORNER = 16;
    public final static int PATH_FROM_BOTTOM_RIGHT_CORNER = 17;
    public final static int LINEAR_FROM_TOP_RIGHT_CORNER = 18;
    public final static int LINEAR_FROM_TOP_LEFT_CORNER = 19;
    public final static int LINEAR_FROM_BOTTOM_RIGHT_CORNER = 20;
    public final static int LINEAR_FROM_BOTTOM_LEFT_CORNER = 21;
    public final static int LINEAR_FROM_CENTER = 22;
    public final static int LINEAR_FROM_CORNERS = 23;
    public final static int PATH_FROM_CORNERS = 24;
    private BufferedImage image = null;
    private BufferedImage circleImage = null;
    private int[] pixels;
    private int[] circlePixels;
    private int[] positions;
    private Color[] colors;
    private int[] rgbs;
    private int alignment;
    private int width;
    private int height;
    public GradientImage(int width, int height, Color[] colors, int alignment){
        image = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        pixels = ((DataBufferInt) image.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
        this.alignment = alignment;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        this.colors = colors;
        rgbs = new int[colors.length];
        for (int i=0;i<rgbs.length;i++){
            rgbs[i] = colors[i].getRGB();
        }
        try{
            renderImage();
        }catch(Exception error){error.printStackTrace();}
    }
    public GradientImage(int width, int height, Color[] colors, int[] positions, int alignment){
        image = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        pixels = ((DataBufferInt) image.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
        this.alignment = alignment;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        this.colors = colors;
        this.positions = positions;
        rgbs = new int[colors.length];
        for (int i=0;i<rgbs.length;i++){
            rgbs[i] = colors[i].getRGB();
        }
        try{
            renderImage();
        }catch(Exception error){error.printStackTrace();}
    }
    public BufferedImage getImage(){
        return image;
    }
    public BufferedImage getImageAsCircle(){
        if (circleImage==null){
            circleImage = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
            circlePixels = ((DataBufferInt) circleImage.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();
            int radius = Math.min(width, height)>>1;
            for (int x=0;x<width;x++){
                for (int y=0;y<height;y++){
                    if (Math.sqrt((Math.max(width>>1, x)-Math.min(width>>1, x))*(Math.max(width>>1, x)-Math.min(width>>1, x))+(Math.max(height>>1, y)-Math.min(height>>1, y))*(Math.max(height>>1, y)-Math.min(height>>1, y)))<=radius){
                        circlePixels[x+y*width] = pixels[x+y*width];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return circleImage;
    }
    private void renderImage() throws Exception{
        if (alignment==LINEAR_LEFT_TO_RIGHT){
            int[] rgbRange = loadRGBRange(width, rgbs, positions);
            for (int x=0;x<width;x++){
                for (int y=0;y<height;y++){
                    pixels[x+y*width] = rgbRange[x];
                }
            }
        }else if (alignment==LINEAR_RIGHT_TO_LEFT){
            int[] rgbRange = loadRGBRange(width, rgbs, positions);
            for (int x=0;x<width;x++){
                for (int y=0;y<height;y++){
                    pixels[x+y*width] = rgbRange[width-x-1];
                }
            }
        }else if (alignment==LINEAR_BOTTOM_TO_TOP){
            int[] rgbRange = loadRGBRange(height, rgbs, positions);
            for (int y=0;y<height;y++){
                for (int x=0;x<width;x++){
                    pixels[x+y*width] = rgbRange[height-y-1];
                }
            }
        }else if (alignment==LINEAR_TOP_TO_BOTTOM){
            int[] rgbRange = loadRGBRange(height, rgbs, positions);
            for (int y=0;y<height;y++){
                for (int x=0;x<width;x++){
                    pixels[x+y*width] = rgbRange[y];
                }
            }
        }else if (alignment==RADIAL_FROM_TOP_LEFT_CORNER){
            int[] rgbRange = loadRGBRange((int) Math.sqrt((width-1)*(width-1)+(height-1)*(height-1)), rgbs, positions);
            for (int x=0;x<width;x++){
                for (int y=0;y<height;y++){
                    pixels[x+y*width] = rgbRange[(int) Math.sqrt((x-1)*(x-1)+(y-1)*(y-1))];
                }
            }
        }else if (alignment==RADIAL_FROM_BOTTOM_LEFT_CORNER){
            int[] rgbRange = loadRGBRange((int) Math.sqrt((width-1)*(width-1)+(height-1)*(height-1)), rgbs, positions);
            for (int x=0;x<width;x++){
                for (int y=0;y<height;y++){
                    pixels[x+(height-y-1)*width] = rgbRange[(int) Math.sqrt((x-1)*(x-1)+(y-1)*(y-1))];
                }
            }
        }else if (alignment==RADIAL_FROM_TOP_RIGHT_CORNER){
            int[] rgbRange = loadRGBRange((int) Math.sqrt((width-1)*(width-1)+(height-1)*(height-1)), rgbs, positions);
            for (int x=0;x<width;x++){
                for (int y=0;y<height;y++){
                    pixels[(width-x-1)+y*width] = rgbRange[(int) Math.sqrt((x-1)*(x-1)+(y-1)*(y-1))];
                }
            }
        }else if (alignment==RADIAL_FROM_BOTTOM_RIGHT_CORNER){
            int[] rgbRange = loadRGBRange((int) Math.sqrt((width-1)*(width-1)+(height-1)*(height-1)), rgbs, positions);
            for (int x=0;x<width;x++){
                for (int y=0;y<height;y++){
                    pixels[(width-x-1)+(height-y-1)*width] = rgbRange[(int) Math.sqrt((x-1)*(x-1)+(y-1)*(y-1))];
                }
            }
        }else if (alignment==RADIAL_FROM_CENTER){
            int[] divArray = divideArray(positions, 2);
            BufferedImage quad1 = new GradientImage(width>>1, height>>1, colors, divArray, GradientImage.RADIAL_FROM_BOTTOM_RIGHT_CORNER).getImage();
            BufferedImage quad2 = new GradientImage(width>>1, height>>1, colors, divArray, GradientImage.RADIAL_FROM_BOTTOM_LEFT_CORNER).getImage();
            BufferedImage quad3 = new GradientImage(width>>1, height>>1, colors, divArray, GradientImage.RADIAL_FROM_TOP_RIGHT_CORNER).getImage();
            BufferedImage quad4 = new GradientImage(width>>1, height>>1, colors, divArray, GradientImage.RADIAL_FROM_TOP_LEFT_CORNER).getImage();
            Graphics2D g = image.createGraphics();
            g.drawImage(quad1, 0, 0, null);
            g.drawImage(quad2, width>>1, 0, null);
            g.drawImage(quad3, 0, height>>1, null);
            g.drawImage(quad4, width>>1, height>>1, null);
            g.dispose();
        }else if (alignment==RADIAL_FROM_CORNERS){
            int[] divArray = divideArray(positions, 2);
            BufferedImage quad1 = new GradientImage(width>>1, height>>1, colors, divArray, GradientImage.RADIAL_FROM_TOP_LEFT_CORNER).getImage();
            BufferedImage quad2 = new GradientImage(width>>1, height>>1, colors, divArray, GradientImage.RADIAL_FROM_TOP_RIGHT_CORNER).getImage();
            BufferedImage quad3 = new GradientImage(width>>1, height>>1, colors, divArray, GradientImage.RADIAL_FROM_BOTTOM_LEFT_CORNER).getImage();
            BufferedImage quad4 = new GradientImage(width>>1, height>>1, colors, divArray, GradientImage.RADIAL_FROM_BOTTOM_RIGHT_CORNER).getImage();
            Graphics2D g = image.createGraphics();
            g.drawImage(quad1, 0, 0, null);
            g.drawImage(quad2, width>>1, 0, null);
            g.drawImage(quad3, 0, height>>1, null);
            g.drawImage(quad4, width>>1, height>>1, null);
            g.dispose();
        }else if (alignment==LINEAR_DIAGONAL_UP){
            int[] rgbRange = loadRGBRange((int) Math.sqrt((width-1)*(width-1)+(height-1)*(height-1)), rgbs, positions);
            for (int x=0;x<width;x++){
                for (int y=0;y<height;y++){
                    pixels[x+(height-y-1)*width] = rgbRange[Math.max(y-x, x-y)];
                }
            }
        }else if (alignment==LINEAR_DIAGONAL_DOWN){
            int[] rgbRange = loadRGBRange((int) Math.sqrt((width-1)*(width-1)+(height-1)*(height-1)), rgbs, positions);
            for (int x=0;x<width;x++){
                for (int y=0;y<height;y++){
                    pixels[x+y*width] = rgbRange[Math.max(y-x, x-y)];
                }
            }
        }else if (alignment==LINEAR_FROM_TOP_RIGHT_CORNER){
            int[] rgbRange = loadRGBRange((width+height)>>1, rgbs, positions);
            for (int x=0;x<width;x++){
                for (int y=0;y<height;y++){
                    pixels[x+(height-y-1)*width] = rgbRange[rgbRange.length-((x+y)>>1)-1];
                }
            }
        }else if (alignment==LINEAR_FROM_TOP_LEFT_CORNER){
            int[] rgbRange = loadRGBRange((width+height)>>1, rgbs, positions);
            for (int x=0;x<width;x++){
                for (int y=0;y<height;y++){
                    pixels[(width-x-1)+(height-y-1)*width] = rgbRange[rgbRange.length-((x+y)>>1)-1];
                }
            }
        }else if (alignment==LINEAR_FROM_BOTTOM_RIGHT_CORNER){
            int[] rgbRange = loadRGBRange((width+height)>>1, rgbs, positions);
            for (int x=0;x<width;x++){
                for (int y=0;y<height;y++){
                    pixels[x+y*width] = rgbRange[rgbRange.length-((x+y)>>1)-1];
                }
            }
        }else if (alignment==LINEAR_FROM_BOTTOM_LEFT_CORNER){
            int[] rgbRange = loadRGBRange((width+height)>>1, rgbs, positions);
            for (int x=0;x<width;x++){
                for (int y=0;y<height;y++){
                    pixels[(width-x-1)+y*width] = rgbRange[rgbRange.length-((x+y)>>1)-1];
                }
            }
        }else if (alignment==LINEAR_FROM_CENTER){
            int[] divArray = divideArray(positions, 2);
            BufferedImage quad1 = new GradientImage(width>>1, height>>1, colors, divArray, GradientImage.LINEAR_FROM_BOTTOM_RIGHT_CORNER).getImage();
            BufferedImage quad2 = new GradientImage(width>>1, height>>1, colors, divArray, GradientImage.LINEAR_FROM_BOTTOM_LEFT_CORNER).getImage();
            BufferedImage quad3 = new GradientImage(width>>1, height>>1, colors, divArray, GradientImage.LINEAR_FROM_TOP_RIGHT_CORNER).getImage();
            BufferedImage quad4 = new GradientImage(width>>1, height>>1, colors, divArray, GradientImage.LINEAR_FROM_TOP_LEFT_CORNER).getImage();
            Graphics2D g = image.createGraphics();
            g.drawImage(quad1, 0, 0, null);
            g.drawImage(quad2, width>>1, 0, null);
            g.drawImage(quad3, 0, height>>1, null);
            g.drawImage(quad4, width>>1, height>>1, null);
            g.dispose();
        }else if (alignment==LINEAR_FROM_CORNERS){
            int[] divArray = divideArray(positions, 2);
            BufferedImage quad1 = new GradientImage(width>>1, height>>1, colors, divArray, GradientImage.LINEAR_FROM_TOP_LEFT_CORNER).getImage();
            BufferedImage quad2 = new GradientImage(width>>1, height>>1, colors, divArray, GradientImage.LINEAR_FROM_TOP_RIGHT_CORNER).getImage();
            BufferedImage quad3 = new GradientImage(width>>1, height>>1, colors, divArray, GradientImage.LINEAR_FROM_BOTTOM_LEFT_CORNER).getImage();
            BufferedImage quad4 = new GradientImage(width>>1, height>>1, colors, divArray, GradientImage.LINEAR_FROM_BOTTOM_RIGHT_CORNER).getImage();
            Graphics2D g = image.createGraphics();
            g.drawImage(quad1, 0, 0, null);
            g.drawImage(quad2, width>>1, 0, null);
            g.drawImage(quad3, 0, height>>1, null);
            g.drawImage(quad4, width>>1, height>>1, null);
            g.dispose();
        }else if (alignment==PATH_FROM_TOP_LEFT_CORNER){
            int[] rgbRange = loadRGBRange(Math.max(width, height), rgbs, positions);
            for (int x=0;x<width;x++){
                for (int y=0;y<height;y++){
                    pixels[x+y*width] = rgbRange[Math.max(x, y)];
                }
            }
        }else if (alignment==PATH_FROM_TOP_RIGHT_CORNER){
            int[] rgbRange = loadRGBRange(Math.max(width, height), rgbs, positions);
            for (int x=0;x<width;x++){
                for (int y=0;y<height;y++){
                    pixels[(width-x-1)+y*width] = rgbRange[Math.max(x, y)];
                }
            }
        }else if (alignment==PATH_FROM_BOTTOM_LEFT_CORNER){
            int[] rgbRange = loadRGBRange(Math.max(width, height), rgbs, positions);
            for (int x=0;x<width;x++){
                for (int y=0;y<height;y++){
                    pixels[x+(height-y-1)*width] = rgbRange[Math.max(x, y)];
                }
            }
        }else if (alignment==PATH_FROM_BOTTOM_RIGHT_CORNER){
            int[] rgbRange = loadRGBRange(Math.max(width, height), rgbs, positions);
            for (int x=0;x<width;x++){
                for (int y=0;y<height;y++){
                    pixels[(width-x-1)+(height-y-1)*width] = rgbRange[Math.max(x, y)];
                }
            }
        }else if (alignment==PATH_FROM_CENTER){
            int[] divArray = divideArray(positions, 2);
            BufferedImage quad1 = new GradientImage(width>>1, height>>1, colors, divArray, GradientImage.PATH_FROM_BOTTOM_RIGHT_CORNER).getImage();
            BufferedImage quad2 = new GradientImage(width>>1, height>>1, colors, divArray, GradientImage.PATH_FROM_BOTTOM_LEFT_CORNER).getImage();
            BufferedImage quad3 = new GradientImage(width>>1, height>>1, colors, divArray, GradientImage.PATH_FROM_TOP_RIGHT_CORNER).getImage();
            BufferedImage quad4 = new GradientImage(width>>1, height>>1, colors, divArray, GradientImage.PATH_FROM_TOP_LEFT_CORNER).getImage();
            Graphics2D g = image.createGraphics();
            g.drawImage(quad1, 0, 0, null);
            g.drawImage(quad2, width>>1, 0, null);
            g.drawImage(quad3, 0, height>>1, null);
            g.drawImage(quad4, width>>1, height>>1, null);
            g.dispose();
        }else if (alignment==PATH_FROM_CORNERS){
            int[] divArray = divideArray(positions, 2);
            BufferedImage quad1 = new GradientImage(width>>1, height>>1, colors, divArray, GradientImage.PATH_FROM_TOP_LEFT_CORNER).getImage();
            BufferedImage quad2 = new GradientImage(width>>1, height>>1, colors, divArray, GradientImage.PATH_FROM_TOP_RIGHT_CORNER).getImage();
            BufferedImage quad3 = new GradientImage(width>>1, height>>1, colors, divArray, GradientImage.PATH_FROM_BOTTOM_LEFT_CORNER).getImage();
            BufferedImage quad4 = new GradientImage(width>>1, height>>1, colors, divArray, GradientImage.PATH_FROM_BOTTOM_RIGHT_CORNER).getImage();
            Graphics2D g = image.createGraphics();
            g.drawImage(quad1, 0, 0, null);
            g.drawImage(quad2, width>>1, 0, null);
            g.drawImage(quad3, 0, height>>1, null);
            g.drawImage(quad4, width>>1, height>>1, null);
            g.dispose();
        }
    }
    public int[] divideArray(int[] array, int div){
        if (array==null){
            return null;
        }
        int[] arr = new int[array.length];
        if (div==2){
            for (int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
                arr[i] = array[i]>>1;
            }
        }else{
            for (int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
                arr[i] = array[i]/div;
            }
        }
        return arr;
    }
    public int[] loadRGBRange(int length, int[] rgbs) throws Exception {
        if (rgbs==null){
            throw new Exception("RGB[]'s cannot be null");
        }
        if (length==0){
            throw new Exception("Length cannot be 0");
        }
        if (rgbs.length==0){
            throw new Exception("RGB[]'s length cannot be 0");
        }
        int[] rgbRange = new int[length];
        if (rgbs.length==1){
            for (int i=0;i<rgbRange.length;i++){
                rgbRange[i] = rgbs[0];
            }
            return rgbRange;
        }
        int[] positions = new int[rgbs.length];
        double pos = 0;
        double block = (double) length/(rgbs.length-1);
        for (int i=0;i<positions.length;i++){
            positions[i] = (int) pos;
            pos+=block;
        }
        int[] as = new int[rgbs.length];
        int[] rs = new int[rgbs.length];
        int[] gs = new int[rgbs.length];
        int[] bs = new int[rgbs.length];
        for (int i=0;i<rgbs.length;i++){
            as[i] = (rgbs[i]>>24) & 0xff;
            rs[i] = (rgbs[i]>>16) & 0xff;
            gs[i] = (rgbs[i]>>8) & 0xff;
            bs[i] = (rgbs[i]) & 0xff;
        }
        int[] adifs = new int[rgbs.length-1];
        int[] rdifs = new int[rgbs.length-1];
        int[] gdifs = new int[rgbs.length-1];
        int[] bdifs = new int[rgbs.length-1];
        for (int i=0;i<rgbs.length-1;i++){
            adifs[i] = as[i]-as[i+1];
            rdifs[i] = rs[i]-rs[i+1];
            gdifs[i] = gs[i]-gs[i+1];
            bdifs[i] = bs[i]-bs[i+1];
        }
        double[] ab = new double[rgbs.length-1];
        double[] rb = new double[rgbs.length-1];
        double[] gb = new double[rgbs.length-1];
        double[] bb = new double[rgbs.length-1];
        for (int i=0;i<rgbs.length-1;i++){
            int l = positions[i+1]-positions[i];
            ab[i] = (double) adifs[i]/l;
            rb[i] = (double) rdifs[i]/l;
            gb[i] = (double) gdifs[i]/l;
            bb[i] = (double) bdifs[i]/l;
        }
        double a = as[0];
        double r = rs[0];
        double g = gs[0];
        double b = bs[0];
        int color = 0;
        for (int i=0;i<rgbRange.length;i++){
            rgbRange[i] = ((int)a<<24)|((int)r<<16)|((int)g<<8)|((int)b);
            if (i+1>positions[0] && i+1<positions[positions.length-1]){
                if (i==positions[color+1]){
                    color++;
                    a = as[color];
                    r = rs[color];
                    g = gs[color];
                    b = bs[color];
                }else{
                    a-=ab[color];
                    r-=rb[color];
                    g-=gb[color];
                    b-=bb[color];
                }
            }
        }
        return rgbRange;
    }
    public int[] loadRGBRange(int length, int[] rgbs, int[] positions) throws Exception {
        if (positions==null){
            return loadRGBRange(length, rgbs);
        }
        if (rgbs==null){
            throw new Exception("RGB[]'s cannot be null");
        }
        if (length==0){
            throw new Exception("Length cannot be 0");
        }
        if (rgbs.length==0 || positions.length==0){
            return null;
        }
        if (positions.length!=rgbs.length){
            throw new Exception("The length of Positions[] must equals the length of RGB[]'s");
        }
        for (int i=0;i<positions.length;i++){
            if (positions[i]>length){
                throw new Exception("Any positions cannot be greater than the length");
            }
        }
        int[] rgbRange = new int[length];
        if (rgbs.length==1){
            for (int i=0;i<rgbRange.length;i++){
                rgbRange[i] = rgbs[0];
            }
            return rgbRange;
        }
        int[] as = new int[rgbs.length];
        int[] rs = new int[rgbs.length];
        int[] gs = new int[rgbs.length];
        int[] bs = new int[rgbs.length];
        for (int i=0;i<rgbs.length;i++){
            as[i] = (rgbs[i]>>24) & 0xff;
            rs[i] = (rgbs[i]>>16) & 0xff;
            gs[i] = (rgbs[i]>>8) & 0xff;
            bs[i] = (rgbs[i]) & 0xff;
        }
        int[] adifs = new int[rgbs.length-1];
        int[] rdifs = new int[rgbs.length-1];
        int[] gdifs = new int[rgbs.length-1];
        int[] bdifs = new int[rgbs.length-1];
        for (int i=0;i<rgbs.length-1;i++){
            adifs[i] = as[i]-as[i+1];
            rdifs[i] = rs[i]-rs[i+1];
            gdifs[i] = gs[i]-gs[i+1];
            bdifs[i] = bs[i]-bs[i+1];
        }
        double[] ab = new double[rgbs.length-1];
        double[] rb = new double[rgbs.length-1];
        double[] gb = new double[rgbs.length-1];
        double[] bb = new double[rgbs.length-1];
        for (int i=0;i<rgbs.length-1;i++){
            int l = positions[i+1]-positions[i];
            ab[i] = (double) adifs[i]/l;
            rb[i] = (double) rdifs[i]/l;
            gb[i] = (double) gdifs[i]/l;
            bb[i] = (double) bdifs[i]/l;
        }
        double a = as[0];
        double r = rs[0];
        double g = gs[0];
        double b = bs[0];
        int color = 0;
        for (int i=0;i<rgbRange.length;i++){
            rgbRange[i] = ((int)a<<24)|((int)r<<16)|((int)g<<8)|((int)b);
            if (i+1>positions[0] && i+1<positions[positions.length-1]){
                if (i==positions[color+1]){
                    color++;
                    a = as[color];
                    r = rs[color];
                    g = gs[color];
                    b = bs[color];
                }else{
                    a-=ab[color];
                    r-=rb[color];
                    g-=gb[color];
                    b-=bb[color];
                }
            }
        }
        return rgbRange;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use the method at http://real-me.net/ddyer/java/imagedemo/imagedemo.java
to apply arbitrary transparency to corresponding jpg images.  Sorry, there
used to be a demo applet but oracle nuked it in their security mania.  You
can see the method in action in all the games at http://boardspace.net/